# Using `find -perm` to find when a permission is not set

Tags: linux, bash, find

I want to find the non-readable files in my directory (eg the files with g-r).  So I tried this:

`find . -perm -g-r`

It shows me all of the files??  So I tried this:

`find . -perm -g+r`

And it showed me only the readable files.  It appears that `-perm -g-r` matches all files.  I'm using CentOS 5.5.  Am I doing something wrong?  It doesn't look like `-perm -g-r` does anything useful.

Comment: I believe that the `-` prefix to the permissions parameter means match files with "at least" these permissions. So it matches files that are not group-readable _as well as_ files that are group-readable, because group-readable files have a group permission that is considered "greater than" `g-r`

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try:

`find . ! -perm -g+r`

Comment: That worked!  I'm still mystified by `-perm -g-r` not working, but oh well.

Comment: It's an obvious extension to find files that are not executable, too. Thanks!

Comment: What if I want to limit my search to files and not directories, and want a `-maxdepth` of 2? I mean, how do I negate the perms while asserting the other things? EDIT: Nevermind. You can negate any option with !. It didn't seem to be working at first, but it really was. I did `find -maxdepth 2 ! -perm -g+r -type d` and found directories to a depth of 2 that did not have group read permission.

Comment: I think the `-perm` option does not support `g-r` as in `chmod g-r <file>`

Answer (score 27):

If you want to find files that are non-readable **by you**, you could use

```
find . ! -readable
```

Comment: This works for Linux, but the BSD find on the Mac (from 2008) doesn't support it.

Comment: Good point. There are probably quite a few versions of find out there that don't support -readable.

Answer (score 0):

on my Debian I need to escape the negation "exclamation mark"
so in your case it would be

```
find . \! -perm -g+r -ls
```

using numbers is also an option. This was my quest:

```
find . \! -perm /444
```

to see what really happens use:

```
find . \! -perm /444 -exec ls -la {} \;
```

Answer (score -3):

You were able to see all files when you executed the below instruction, because you were executing it as root.

```
find . -perm -g-r
```

Try executing as a normal user.

Comment: File attributes (permissions, ownership, size, etc.) do not depend on the user. I believe your answer is wrong.

Comment: Also, OP asked how to find bits *not* set, which Tim Cooper's answer does and yours misses.