# How can I properly check delete/write permissions for a folder hierarchy?

Tags: bash

In a script I'm working on, I want to `rm -rf` a folder hierarchy. But before doing so, I want to make sure the process can complete successfully. So, this is the approach I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset
set -o errexit

BASE=$1
# Check if we can delete the target base folder
echo -n "Testing write permissions in $BASE..."
if ! find $BASE \( -exec test -w {} \; -o \( -exec echo {} \; -quit \) \) | xargs -I {} bash -c "if [ -n "{}" ]; then echo Failed\!; echo {} is not writable\!; exit 1; fi"; then
  exit 1
fi
echo "Succeeded"

rm -rf $BASE
```

Now I'm wondering if there might be a better solution (more readable, shorter, reliable, etc).

Please note that I am fully aware of the fact that there could be changes in file access permissions between the check and the actual removal. In my use case, that is acceptable (compared to not doing any checks). If there was a way to avoid this though, I'd love to know how.

Answer (score 6):

Are you aware of the `-perm` switch of `find` (if it is present in your version)?

```
find -perm -u+w
```

Comment: No, I wasn't. Thanks for the hint. I'll take that into consideration.

Comment: Ok, I give up. How can I properly inverse the test? Your example lists all files I have write access to. How do I list all files I don't have write access to? I can't get it to work.  `find . ! -perm -u+w` lists nothing, while my original approach lists tons of files.

Comment: @fge That doesn't list anything either (testing on Debian 6). `find . ! -writable` works great, but according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4382672/259953 it might be less portable.

Comment: I marked your solution as the correct one even though I never got it to work. But I hope that's a problem with my specific version of find and/or environment.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: What about `find -not -perm -u+w` instead of `!` that can get interpreted by the history expansion of your shell?

Comment: @choroba No, that makes no difference. The `!` doesn't cause any trouble when using `-writable`. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Access Control Lists maybe?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Heh. The `-perm -u+w` checks whether the file is writable by its owner, not by the user running `find`.

Comment: @choroba That explains a lot.