# how to find directories without access permissions ?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using `find -perm` to find when a permission is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382599/using-find-perm-to-find-when-a-permission-is-not-set)

I have a list of directories in which some do not have access permissions.
How can I create an array so that it contains only accessible directories using csh.

My code looks like as follow :

```
set array = (`find $path_to directories -type d -name "*_xyz"`)
```

it gives me whole list of directories matches to _xyz extension including without access permissions dir as well but I dont want them to be in list.

Comment: You can add `-perm` flags to the `find` command line, it's not clear from your questions what permissions exactly you are looking for but this should hopefully get you started.

Comment: I'm resisting the urge to post a link to http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: actually I need to cd to each directory in the $array. bt when it reach to a non accessible directory program halts . how can I avoid this so that my loop simply go to the next directory. code is foreach dir ($array) cd $dir echo "directory is $dir" cd - end .. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set array = (`find . -type d -perm /g+x,o+x -name "*_xyz"`)
```

with that -perm parameters it search only folders accessible by the owner or the group